# How to find P-values for ATT in PSM

Tags: stata, att, p-value, significance, propensity-score-matching

I have estimated ATT in PSM using psmatch2 command.
I get only the T-stat values for the ATT.
How to determine the significance level? How to know whether I should use * or ** or ***?

I ran the following command

*estimates table, star(.05 .01 .001)*

But it provides results for the unmatched sample only.

How to find the significance levels for ATT